# "… einiger betriebener …" oder "… einiger betriebenen …"

Tags: verb, adjective

Ich bin vor einiger Zeit auf folgenden Satz gestoßen und habe mich seitdem immer wieder gefragt, wie es korrekt heißen muss oder was sich besser anhört:

> Der Datenbestand einiger im Internet betriebenen so genannten »Social Networks« wie »MySpace« oder den »Lokalisten.de« ist enorm.

oder

> Der Datenbestand einiger im Internet betriebener so genannter »Social Networks« wie »MySpace« oder »Lokalisten.de« ist enorm.

Und wie nennt man dieses Prinzip?

Answer (score 8):

Takkat ([Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5137/einiger-betriebener-oder-einiger-betriebenen/5138#5138) wurde gelöscht) hat schon richtig auf den Grundsatz hingewiesen, dass die Flexion des Adjektivs davon abhängt, ob das Nomen determiniert ist:

> Wenn ein Adjektiv mit einem bestimmten oder unbestimmten Artikel begleitet ist (hier "einige") dann wird das Adjektiv stark oder schwach gebeugt.

Nur was die Anwendung dieses Grundsatzes auf das Beispiel betrifft, sehe ich die Dinge etwas anders. Im ursprünglichen Beispiel

> Der Datenbestand einiger im Internet betriebenen so genannten »Social Networks« [...] ist enorm.

ist das Nomen "Social Network" jedenfalls nicht durch einen Artikel determiniert. Sonst würde es lauten:

> Der Datenbestand der im Internet betriebenen so genannten »Social Networks« [...] ist enorm.

Es ist aber auch nicht komplett undeterminiert:

> Der Datenbestand im Internet betriebener so genannter »Social Networks« [...] ist enorm.

Vielmehr wird es durch ein Zahlwort "einige" näher eingegrenzt. Laut [canoo ist "einige" ein Anwendungsfall der "schwankenden Flexion"](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html?MenuId=Word3133#Anchor-einige-14210), bei der sich die Flexion des Adjektivs nach der Endung von "einige" richtet. Im Plural soll demnach das Adjektiv stark flektiert werden, also:

> Der Datenbestand einiger im Internet betriebener so genannter »Social Networks« [...] ist enorm.

Canoo.net scheint aber auch die schwache Form für zulässig zu halten - Zitat des Beispielsatzes:

> trotz einiger größerer Missverständnisse (seltener auch: trotz einiger größeren Missverständnisse)

Die schwach flektierte Variante des letzten Beispiels widerspricht aber zumindest meinem Sprachgefühl, sie klingt m.E. etwas „holprig“.

Comment: erwartet "trotz" im letzten Beispiel nicht den Dativ? "Trotz einigen größeren Missverständnissen?" vgl. Genitiv mit wegen: "Wegen einiger größerer Missverständnisse..." Im Beispiel ist es die neuerdings tolerierte Genitiv-Konstruktion mit "trotz", die in meinen Ohren schmerzt :-D

Comment: "Neuerdings toleriert"? Schon im Grimm'schen Wörterbuch wird der Dativ als _"ursprünglich, heute bereits selten"_ bezeichnet, auch wenn die Autoren sich deutlich positionieren: _"jünger ist der gebrauch mit dem genitiv; er ist erst um die mitte des 18. jhs. bezeugt (s. 3) und gilt bei Adelung und Campe noch als unrichtig; heute hat er den dativ fast ganz verdrängt: troz unsrer unzähligen moralischen schrifften noch nicht tief genug untersucht "_ Auch der Duden sieht das etwas differenzierter, betrachtet den Genitiv m.E. als Normalfall und verlangt Dativ in definierten Ausnahmefällen.

Comment: Da spielt dann wohl meine Deutschlehrerin eine Rolle - "Das könnt ihr euch am Wort 'trotzdem' merken: 'Dem' ist welcher Fall? Also!" :-D Danke für das Zitat. War mir nicht bewusst, dass bereits solange um Genitiv und Dativ gestritten wird :)

Answer (score 1):

Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* schwankt die Deklination nach Pronominaladjektiven wie *alle, einige* oder *manche*, je nachdem, ob diese Wörter als Artikelwort oder als Adjektiv behandelt werden.

Wenn das vorangehende Pronominaladjektiv als Artikelwort gebraucht wird, werden Adjektive und Partizipien schwach dekliniert:

> alle schönen Bücher

Wenn das vorangehende Pronominaladjektiv als Adjektiv gebraucht wird, werden beide Wörter parallel (also stark) flektiert:

> einige schöne Bücher

​
Im Singular ist die Flexion nach *einige* nicht einheitlich:

> einiger poetischer Geist
>
> das Vorhandensein einiger poetischer Begabung
>
> einigen poetischen Geistes / Verständnisses
> (veraltend: einiges poetischen Geistes / Verständnisses)
>
> einiges alte Gerümpel
> (selten: einiges altes Gerümpel)
>
> bei einigem guten Willen
> (bei einigem gutem Willen)
>
> bei einigem poetischen Verständnis
> (bei einigem poetischem Verständnis)

Im Plural wird das Adjektiv bzw. Partizip nach *einige* in der Regel parallel (stark) flektiert:

> einige gute Menschen
> einiger guter Menschen
> einigen guten Menschen

Im Genitiv erscheint gelegentlich schwache Flexion:

> einiger guten Menschen

​
Sofern man die zuletzt genannte, nur gelegentlich erscheinende Form vernachlässigt, sollten daher die betroffenen Wörter in dem in der Frage gegebenen Satz in der Regel parallel (stark) flektiert werden:

> Der Datenbestand *einiger* im Internet *betriebener* so *genannter* »Social Networks« …
> (*analog:* einiger guter Menschen)