# Zur schwankenden Deklination. Kriterien zur entsprechenden Wahl (stark oder schwach)?

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending

Laut [canno.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html) sei *schwankende Deklination* etwas zwischen starker und schwacher Deklination. Zum Beispiel gehöre das Indefinitpronomen *andere* zu dieser Gruppe,

> mit anderem gutem Bier *oder* mit anderem guten Bier

seien beide erlaubt. Zahlreiche Beispiele können da gefunden werden. Ich zitiere ein paar nur:

**Beispiele:**

> 1. folgendes interessantes Beispiel   **oder**    folgendes interessante
> 2. irgendwelches altes Zeug   **oder**    irgendwelches alte Zeug
> 3. mit sämtlicher anwesenden Prominenz **oder**   mit sämtlicher anwesender Prominenz

- Welche Deklinationsart ist zu wählen? Die, die mehr Information enthält, die aber nach Wiederholung klingen könnte (stark), oder die quasi kompakte (schwach).

Comment: wenn ich das so anschaue, bevorzuge ich als Muttersprachler die dopplung --> es,es / es,es / er,er

Comment: Hier kommen die Deutschen mit der komplizierten doppelten Adjektivdeklination ins Schleudern. Es gibt einfach Fälle, wo sich dieses Doppelsystem selbst aushebelt und man kann nur sagen, das ist ein unsicherer Bereich.

Comment: Also ich würde nur sagen: mit anderem guten Bier, folgendes interessante Beispiel, irgendwelches altes Zeug, (mit sämtlicher anwesenden Prominenz). Die Formulierung in Klammer finde ich unschön. Aber ich bin sicher, andere würden das anders machen.

Comment: Haben wir schon einen Nacht-Chat "Zur schwankenden Deklination"?

Comment: Related: [“… einiger betriebener …” oder “… einiger betriebenen …”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5137/einiger-betriebener-oder-einiger-betriebenen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich glaube, das lässt sich so pauschal nicht sagen.

> Folgendes interessantes Beispiel... klingt gut
>
> mit folgendem interessantem Beispiel... klingt für mich furchtbar
>
> Mit anderem guten Bier... geht
>
> Anderes gute Bier... ist falsch

Die Wörter bekommen jeweils eine andere FUnktion zugewiesen und fühlen sich anders an, jedoch steht dahinter meiner Ansicht nach kein System... zumindest nix einfaches.

Mehr Informationen enthält übgridens keine der Varianten. Wenn, dann mehr Redundanz.
Go with the flow.

Comment: "mit folgendem interessantem Beispiel" klingt nicht nur furchtbar, es ist (Dativ!) ein klassischer Anlass für die Mischdeklination: "mit folgendem interessanten Beispiel". Ein (relativ offenes) System gibt es allerdings schon, siehe die nächste Antwort.

Answer (score 2):

In *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 6. Aufl. Mannheim 2007* wird die folgende Erklärung angegeben:

> Die Deklination nach Pronominaladjektiven schwankt, je nachdem, ob diese Wörter als Artikelwort oder als Adjektiv behandelt werden. Adjektive oder Partizipien werden schwach dekliniert, wenn das vorangehende Pronominaladjektiv als Artikelwort gebraucht wird: *alle guten Tipps.* Wird es als Adjektiv gebraucht, dann werden beide parallel flektiert: *einige schöne Bücher.*

Speziell zu den vier in der Frage genannten Zweifelsfällen findet man darüber hinaus:

**folgende**

> Wenn *folgend* kein Artikelwort vorausgeht, gilt: Nach *folgend* wird das [substantivierte] Adjektiv oder Partizip im Singular meist schwach flektiert (*folgend* verhält sich hier also wie ein Artikelwort): *folgender überraschende Anblick* (Werfel); *folgender Angestellte; nach folgendem wirksamen Prinzip* (Kirst). Im Plural wird überwiegend stark flektiert (*folgend* verhält sich hier wie ein Adjektiv, es kann durch jedes andere Adjektiv ersetzt werden): *folgende auffallende Fakten* (Bergengruen); *wegen folgender beleidigender Äußerungen; wegen folgender Abgeordneter.* Die schwache Flexion ist aber ebenfalls gebräuchlich und korrekt: *folgende interessanten Sätze* (Kesten); *wegen folgender wichtigen Ereignisse; die Wortmeldungen folgender Abgeordneten.*

**andere**

> Das auf *ander-* folgende [substantivierte] Adjektiv oder Partizip wird heute überwiegend in gleicher Weise (parallel) flektiert: *anderes gedrucktes Material, bei anderer seelischer Verfassung, eine Menge anderer wertvoller Gegenstände; ein anderer Abgeordneter, die anderen Beamten, die Forderungen anderer Betroffener.* Nur im Dativ Singular Maskulinum und Neutrum wird häufig schwach flektiert: *aus anderem wertvollen Material, zwischen anderem wertlosen Gerümpel, mit anderem Neuen.* Sonst ist die schwache Flexion veraltet und kommt nur noch selten vor: *anderes alte Zeug.*

**irgendwelche**

> Folgt dem Indefinitpronomen *irgendwelcher* ein [substantiviertes] Adjektiv oder Partizip, dann kann dieses schwach oder stark flektiert werden: *irgendwelches dumme / dummes Zeug; mit irgendwelchem alten / altem Plunder; von irgendwelcher tierischen / tierischer Herkunft; die Meinung irgendwelcher klugen / kluger Leute, irgendwelcher Angestellten / Angestellter.*

**sämtliche**

> Das auf *sämtlich* folgende Adjektiv (Partizip) wird im Singular stark oder schwach flektiert: *sämtliches irdisches / irdische Leben, sämtlicher aufgehäufte[r] Sand, der Verlust sämtlicher vorhandener / vorhandenen Energie, mit sämtlichem gesammeltem / (häufiger:) gesammelten Material, sämtliches vorhandene[s] Eigentum beschlagnahmen.* Bei substantivierten Adjektiven und im Plural herrscht im Allgemeinen die schwache Flexion vor: *sämtliches Irdische; sämtliche griechischen Bücher, sämtliche Beamten, sämtliche Gefangenen, für sämtliche anwesenden Bürger. ... [die] Mitglieder sämtlicher deutschen Parteien.* Im Nominativ und Akkusativ Plural tritt die starke Deklination recht selten auf: *… dass Großbritannien nahezu sämtliche internationale Verträge kündigen müsste* (F. A.  Z.). Im Genitiv Plural ist die starke Deklination etwas verbreiteter: *die Kleidung sämtlicher Gefangener, die Abbestellung sämtlicher wissenschaftlicher Zeitschriften.* Aber auch hier sind die schwachen Formen insgesamt häufiger als die starken: *die Abbestellung sämtlicher wissenschaftlichen Zeitschriften.*

Comment: Ich frage mich, wieviele Deutsche davon je was gehört haben. Das sind Probleme, mit denen sich Journalisten, Schriftsteller und Lektoren herumschlagen mUssen - und natürlich die Duden-Leute.