# Die Deklination des Adjektives nach dem Pronomen

Tags: grammar, adjective, pronoun, declension, adjective-ending

Es wird gelehrt, dass nach einigen Pronomina die Deklination wie nach einem definiertem Artikel stattfinden und nach den Anderen - wie nach einem undefiniertem.

Was ist die Quelle dieser Teilung? Warum deklinieren die Adjektiven unterschieden nach verschiedenen Pronomina?

Comment: Kannst du Beispiele beitragen? Ich verstehe aus dem Blauen heraus nicht, was du meinst …

Comment: @Jan: Ich vermute, es geht um Demonstrativ-, Indefinit-, Possessivpronomina und so etwas; etwa _dieses grüne Fahrrad_, _irgendein grünes Fahrrad_, _mein grünes Fahrrad_. Die Antwort dürfte in die Richtung laufen, daß manche Pronomina KNG schon hinreichend markieren, so daß starke Adjektivflexion doppelt gemoppelt wäre, und andere nicht.

Comment: Ähnlich: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10739

Comment: @c.p.: Artikelwörter sind Pronomina. (Die Umkehrung gilt nicht.)

Comment: Der Beispiel: warum ist es "einige hohe Häuser" aber "manche hohen Häuser"? Verknüpftes ist ähnlich, aber warum wurde "einige" wie ein Adjektiv betrachtet und "manche" als ein Artikel?

Comment: @marmistrz Na ja, ich glaube bei beiden geht beides. Hier in http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Artikelwort.html?MenuId=Word3134 wird eigentlich als solche für beide Artikelwörter gekennzeichnet: schwankende Deklination.

Comment: Ja aber es wird nicht erklärt **warum** die Deklination von etwelche oder etliche stark ist und von welche - schwach ist. Ich möchte tiefer gehen - **warum** ist es so?