# "Existenz solcher seelischer/n Vorgänge"

Tags: grammar, adjective, pronoun, declension, adjective-ending

Ich bin mal wieder (obwohl ich Muttersprachler bin) von der deutschen Grammatik verwirrt. In Freuds Vorlesungen zur Psychoanalyse von 1916 bin ich auf Folgendes gestoßen:

> die Existenz solcher seelische**r** Vorgänge

Ich würde aber viel eher sagen:

> die Existenz solcher seelische**n** Vorgänge

Denn man sagt ja auch

> die Existenz dieser seelischen Vorgänge

Welche Schreibweise ist richtig und ganz besonders wieso?

Und wie würde man es bei Wörtern sagen wie:

- jener
- aller
- keiner
- mancher
- vieler
- usw.

**-n oder -r und wieso?**

Comment: related: [Zur schwankenden Deklination. Kriterien zur entsprechenden Wahl (stark oder schwach)?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10739/9551)

Comment: related: [“… einiger betriebener …” oder “… einiger betriebenen …”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5137/9551)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Varianten ist der zwischen [schwacher und starker Deklination](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/index.html?MenuId=Word313#Anchor-Deklinationstypen-35882) des Adjektivs. Zum Deklination nach *solcher* schreibt [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html#Anchor-solcher-48213):

> Ohne Artikelwort vor solch- wird das nachfolgende Adjektiv meistens schwach flektiert. Vor allem im Plural kommt aber auch die starke Flexion vor.

Es ist also beides richtig, die von Dir bevorzugte Variante ist üblicher (heute, möchte ich einschränken - es könnte zu Freuds Zeit anders gewesen sein).

Unter dem Link findest Du auch Angaben zu den anderen von Dir angefragten Pronomen und Zahladjektiven.