# »Einige möglichen Ursachen sollen beleuchtet werden.«

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective, adjective-ending

Die Autokorrektur von Word meldete einen Grammatikfehler in:

> Einige möglichen Ursachen sollen beleuchtet werden.

Stattdessen wird *mögliche* vorgeschlagen. Ich nahm vermutlich an, dass die *Ursachen* ein indirektes Akkusativobjekt des Verbs darstellen, was *möglichen* erlauben würde. Ist das gerechtfertigt?

Comment: Das **n** wäre auch im Akkusativ falsch: https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:möglich http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html

Comment: @CarstenS Ich habe mir deine sehr interessanten Links angesehen. Allerdings klang es dort für mich so, als wäre die Form mit "n" hier genau die richtige? Wie sollte ich das Diagramm dort lesen?

Comment: Die Tabelle zeigt erst einmal, dass sich im Plural die Nominativformen nicht von den Akkusativformen unterscheiden. Die Frage ist damit lediglich, ob die starke Deklination genommen werden muss oder oder nicht. Das ist nach „einige“ etwas verwirrend, aber der zweite Link sagt, dass im Plural ein Adjektiv nach „einige“ stark zu deklinieren ist. *Einige Mögliche Ursachen beleuchten wegen einiger möglicher Ursachen mit einigen möglichen Ursachen einige mögliche Ursachen ;)* (Ohne Sinn aber mit vier Fällen.)

Comment: Ich finde, es ist klarer bei einer separaten Betrachtung von "Einige Ursachen... " und "Mögliche Ursachen... ".

Comment: @Iris, nur wenn du schon weißt, dass stark zu deklinieren ist.

Comment: @CarstenS, ja, aber die Deklination von "Einige Ursachen" stand ja nicht in Frage. Warum sollte dann "möglich" in dem Moment anders dekliniert werden?

Comment: @Iris es würde es, stünde da *keine* statt *einige*.

Comment: _Einige **der** mögliche**n** Ursachen …_ und _**Die / Alle / Seine** mögliche**n** Ursachen …_, aber _**Zwei / Viele / Einzelne / Bestimmte / ∅** mögliche Ursachen sollen beleuchtet werden_. Grob gesagt: Wenn das Adjektiv die durch (definiten) Artikel, Pronomen oder Numeral bestimmte Gesamtmenge einschränkt, dann schwach, aber wenn die vom Adjektiv aufgespannte Extension vom Determinierer näher bestimmt wird oder beide gleichwertig nebeneinander – evtl. sogar mit Komma dazwischen – stehen, dann stark. _die, alle_ ≥ _möglichen_; _zwei, viele, einzelne, einige, bestimmte_ ≤ _mögliche_.

Comment: Related: [“… einiger betriebener …” oder “… einiger betriebenen …”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5137/9551) and [Zur schwankenden Deklination. Kriterien zur entsprechenden Wahl (stark oder schwach)?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10739/9551)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Kernaussage ist im Nominativ Plural - Wer/Was soll beleuchtet werden:

> "Mögliche Ursachen sollen beleuchtet werden." (starke Deklination, Plural)

Das Wort "Einige" gibt eine nicht näher bestimmte Anzahl vor. "Einige" wird ebenso wie "mögliche" mit dem Substantiv zusammen dekliniert. Es könnte auch eine konkrete Zahl dort stehen:

> "Einige/Vier mögliche Ursachen sollen beleuchtet werden." (starke Deklination, Plural)

Eine Variante mit "möglichen" ergibt sich hier unter Verwendung des Genitivs:

> "Einige/Vier *der* möglichen Ursachen sollen beleuchtet werden." (schwache Deklination, Genitiv pl.)

Bezieht man sich auf "Alle" Ursachen und nutzt dafür den bestimmten Artikel:

> "Die/Alle möglichen Ursachen sollen beleuchtet werden." (schwache Deklination, Plural)

Will man die Ursachen nicht betrachten und nutzt "keine":

> "Keine möglichen Ursachen sollen beleuchtet werden." (gemischte Deklination, Plural)

negiert man die Aussage ohne Angabe eine Menge, wird daraus wiederum:

> "Mögliche Ursachen sollen *nicht* beleuchtet werden."
>
> (Verwendung ohne bestimmten Artikel, starke Deklination, Plural)

Hintergrund ist der Unterschied zwischen starker und schwacher Deklination des Wortes "möglich" als Plural in Verbindung mit "Ursachen". Bei Angabe eines bestimmten Artikels setzt die schwache Deklination ein, ohne Angabe eines Artikels wird stark dekliniert. "Mögliche Ursachen" ist im Nominativ.

Nähere Informationen zur Deklination (Flexion) des Wortes "möglich" unter:

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:m%C3%B6glich

Comment: Die starke Deklination des folgenden Adjektivs nach „keine“ im Nominativ und Akkusativ Plural („keine mögliche Ursachen“) kam jedoch früher gelegentlich vor, gilt allerdings laut Duden als veraltet.

Answer (score 6):

Nein, es handelt sich um einen Passiv-Satz, und im Passiv steht kein Akkusativobjekt. Stattdessen ist das inhaltliche Objekt das syntaktische Subjekt und steht daher im Nominativ. (Alle Passivkonstruktionen verwenden das Hilfsverb 'werden', aber nicht immer als finites Verb. Hier ist das Modalverb 'sollen' das finite Verb.)

Answer (score 0):

Meiner Erfahrung nach treten derartige Verwirrungen vor allem bei Adjektiven auf, die an zweiter Stelle in einer Reihung von Attributen stehen. Die richtige Form findet man oft, indem man probeweise das erste Attribut löscht:

```
Einige möglichen Ursachen // keine Ahnung
// also lassen wir mal das Adjektiv weg
Einige Ursachen // jo, klingt doch richtig
// probieren wir jetzt mal das Adjektiv ohne Pronomen
Möglichen Ursachen // woa, das kling ja voll falsch
// mal das "n" weg
Mögliche Ursachen // ja, jetzt klingt's richtig
// tun wir das zweite Attribut wieder dazu
Einige mögliche Ursachen // klingt tatsächlich besser
// und es macht auch Sinn,
// weil man ja auch ein Komma hinzufügen kann,
// ohne die Bedeutung zu verändern
Einige, mögliche Ursachen
```

Hier noch zwei Artikel des Instituts für deutsche Sprache, die erklären, dass eine parallele Flexion grundsätzlich richtig ist, aber trotzdem manchmal das zweite Adjektiv schwach flektiert wird:

- http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/gruwi.ansicht?v_id=4049
- http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_id=44

Nach diesen Artikeln ist "einige möglichen Ursachen" nicht falsch, sondern "einige" ist stark und "möglichen" ist schwach flektiert. Vermutungen aus deskriptiver Perspektive, warum die Sprecher so sprechen, finden sich in den Artikeln.

Comment: Methode ist OK, nur ist "einige" kein Adjektiv.

Comment: Warum machst du aus "Adjektiv" nicht einfach "mit dem Substantiv zu deklinierendes Wort"? Damit hättest du dich fein aus der Affäre gezogen und die Antwort wäre richtiger.

Comment: Okay, okay, hab's verbessert, @tofro.

Comment: Würde das nicht fehlschlagen, wenn man statt mit "einige" mit "keine" beginnt?

Comment: @mafu Weil das keine Reihung ist. "Keine, mögliche(n) Ursachen" (mit Komma) geht ja nicht. An einem anderen Beispiel wird es vielleicht deutlicher: "Hier gibt's keine schnellen Autos." Könnte man ein Komma einfügen ("Hier gibt's keine, schnelle Autos."), dann würde das bedeuten, dass es hier schnelle Autos gibt *und* dass er hier keine Autos gibt, das schließt sich aber aus. "Keine" wird also nicht gereiht, sondern es verneint die gesamte folgende Phrase, so: `keine (möglichen Ursachen)`, und da braucht es dann einen anderen Kasus.

Answer (score 0):

Nach "einige", "viele", "wenige", "mehrere" und nach Zahlwörtern braucht man die **starke Deklination**. "Einige mögliche Ursachen" ist Subjekt des Satzes, und die stark deklinierte Form von "möglich" im Nominativ Plural ist "mögliche". Deswegen schlägt die Autokorrektur "Einige mögliche Ursachen..." vor.